# How can I add an underline with a custom color to a link in a Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I am trying to make.

[image]

In case it's not clear, the black navbar link has a purple underline. What would be a nice way to add such a thing to a link in Bootstrap's navbar? Should I squeeze in a div under the link? Any other ideas? Is something with box shadows possible?

Answer (score 2):

IS this the answer you looked for?

```
<ul>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Jobs</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px; 
    font-family:arial; 
  }

li:hover {
  border-bottom:1px solid purple;
  }
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rk83r0xn/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  }
li {
  display:inline-block;
  }
li:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom:2px solid purple;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

or

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
li:nth-child(2):after {
  content: '\A';
 height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like your first solution, but it doesn't give me the exact effect that I'm going for. Links in Bootstrap's navbar are as tall as the navbar itself. That's why I asked this question here. I couldn't get any method to work specifically in this navbar. Still, I'll ask the client if this looks nice: http://i.imgur.com/1Rr4iUf.png

Comment: Then use the second option and adjust the bottom position.

Comment: Any way to make the second one match the length of the word?

Answer (score 0):

.navbar ul li a{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
You can set the with of this border too if needed.